# Can I change a LICENSE file text format?

Tags: license-notice, license-file

Using a text format utility, (e.g. [`par`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par_(command))) I would like to know if either/both of the following are permitted:

1. Adjust paragraph width or center/justify text.
2. Distribute as a `.md` Markdown file so as to highlight `#` headers and/or add bullet lists to individual articles/clauses.

Comment: Edited. I think they are related, but different.

Comment: Possibly, even probably, but that's why we flag potential duplicates. It brings it to the attention of other reviewers and then consensus rules.

Comment: I agree it's not a full dupe, but still vote to close as a full dupe as the accepted answer is pretty much applicable here (though it could maybe use some community edits to bring it to a canonical answer)

Comment: Maybe they should be merged?

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible, but sounds fine to me

Comment: @JorgeBucaran we only merge posts on exceptionally rare occasions: when it does the community no good to have separate spots for answers, and when the questions are identical to each other.

Comment: @kdopen I personally see the two questions as different: the other question asked whether they can change the `(c) 2015 Zizouz212` to something else, this one if they can make changes to the license document itself. I see those as being very distinct.

Comment: @Zizouz212 The question asks about all typographic changes to the license, not only the copyright line. But even in that case, it might be a dupe of [Can I change the caps to lowercase in licenses?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/13/190)

Comment: So what I think is we have a cluster of similar questions, which need to be 'merged'  in some way to a canonical 'Can I change anything about a license format' question with one or more answers to address different aspects (typographical, font/CAPS, (c) to a Unicode character, etc).

Answer (score -1):

As long as you don't change the contents of the file itself, you're fine. If you change the formatting, or even the caps of the text of the license, you are essentially creating a derivative work: caps and formatting have significance in the law. One such example is here: [Can I change the caps to lowercase in licenses?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-i-change-the-caps-to-lowercase-in-licenses)

I'm not quite sure why you would do this. Just leave the license in a text file in your repository and it's fine.

Comment: You said `If you change the formatting, or even the caps of the text of the license, you are essentially creating a derivative work:`. So, is it still permissible or not? Thanks.

Comment: @George No it is not.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Do licenses specify a minimum line width (think about uses that have to display them on surfaces other than computer screens, too)? Do they require to be set within <pre></pre> on websites?

Comment: @Zizouz212 From the other question "If I make some typographical changes to the default ... license" which is what this is addressing. But that's what VtC reviews are for :)

Comment: That previous comment was meant to be in response to the question :(