# Why is this text usually uppercase in licenses?

Tags: licensing

Many FLOSS licenses contain a variant of the following text:

> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
>   OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
>   ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
>   OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

In short licenses, it stands out that this is all uppercase. Does it have any legal implications, or is it just an aesthetic thing?

Comment: See also: [Can I change the caps to lowercase in licenses?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-i-change-the-caps-to-lowercase-in-licenses)

Comment: IT'S USUALLY A SCAREDY CAT MOVE ON THE PART OF THE ORIGINAL PRODUCER PLEADING THAT THOSE WHO WOULD TAKE THEIR WORK NOT ATTEMPT TO INFLICT FURTHER DAMAGES.  SEE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indemnity